# Exclude first and last record using BCP

Tags: sql-server, bcp

My file, `.xx1`, has the following format:

> 00|20140115
>   01|1234|A|5009|NewYork
>   01|12345|B|300|Dallas
>   01|12345|B|300|Texas
>   99|20140115|2

To load the above file into a table I have used below BCP command

> `%BCP% Test.dbo.test1 IN test.xx1 -S servername -T - F 2 -t^| -c`

It loads the data from 3rd record to 4th record

> 01|12345|B|300|Dallas
>   01|12345|B|300|Texas

It excludes the header as well as one more record `01|1234|A|5009|NewYork` and it automatically excludes the last record.

Thanks, 
Ramesh

Comment: Have you looked at this solution as an option? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880812/bcp-unexpected-eof

Comment: Your flag `-F 2` excludes first 2 rows. What you need is `-L` Last Row indicator.

Comment: No. As the [MSFT doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) says, "-F Specifies the number of the first row to ... import from a data file". So `-F 2` above says that 1 row, the header, should be ignored when importing the data file.